# Dates converting incorrectly in R

Tags: r, date

I have written this piece of code:

Everything in this code is working great, except for that last line. Essentially, If the date for Invoicing is greater than the date for Invoiced, then I want it to find the biggest value between the two and replace invoicing.

The code runs but messes up my date format. Before the code runs, date is in YYYY-MM-DD format. After running the code, a date like 2021-10-12 turns into 18912.

Any idea why this might be happening?

I also tried adding:

`%>% as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01")` to the end but that gave me the following error:

Error in as.Date.default(., origin = "1970-01-01") :
do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”

```
df1 <- left_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  mutate(New = coalesce(New, New2)) %>% 
  mutate(New =  pmin(New, Approved, Processed, Rejected, Expired, Pending, Has_Note, Invoice.Pending, Invoicing, Invoiced, Invoice.Rejected, Invoice.Rejected.Needs.Credit, Credited, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-New2) %>% 
  mutate(Invoicing = ifelse(Invoicing > Invoiced, max(Invoicing, Invoiced), Invoicing))
```

dputs:

> dput(head(df1, 20))
> structure(list(Coach340BClaimsID = c(206L, 629L, 4174L, 5302L,
> 5314L, 5904L, 7439L, 7948L, 8268L, 8302L, 10556L, 10893L, 11681L,
> 12133L, 12479L, 12738L, 13145L, 13614L, 14474L, 15187L), Pending = structure(c(NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"),
> Rejected = structure(c(18943, 18943, NA, 18943, 18943, NA,
> 18810, NA, NA, 18943, 18824, NA, NA, 18943, 18946, 18829,
> 18943, 18943, 18946, 18946), class = "Date"), Approved = structure(c(NA,
> NA, 18788, NA, NA, 18810, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), New = structure(c(NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_), class = "Date"), Has_Note = structure(c(NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_), class = "Date"), Processed = structure(c(NA, NA,
> 18788, NA, NA, 18810, NA, 18753, 18750, NA, NA, 18753, 18751,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Expired = structure(c(NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_), class = "Date"), Invoice.Pending = structure(c(NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_), class = "Date"), Invoicing = structure(c(NA, NA,
> 18842, NA, NA, 18922, NA, 18842, 18842, NA, NA, 18842, 18842,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Invoiced = structure(c(NA,
> NA, 18842, NA, NA, 18932, NA, 18838, 18842, NA, NA, 18842,
> 18838, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Invoice.Rejected = structure(c(NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_), class = "Date"), Invoice.Rejected.Needs.Credit = structure(c(NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_), class = "Date"), Credited = structure(c(NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
> NA_real_), class = "Date"), Tier2_ID = c("MN02", "MN02",
> "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02",
> "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02",
> "MN02", "MN02")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(df2, 20))
> structure(list(Coach340BClaimsID = c(206L, 629L, 4174L, 5302L,
> 5314L, 5904L, 7439L, 7948L, 8268L, 8302L, 10556L, 10893L, 11681L,
> 12133L, 12479L, 12738L, 13145L, 13614L, 14474L, 15187L), Tier2_ID = c("MN02",
> "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02",
> "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02", "MN02",
> "MN02", "MN02", "MN02"), New2 = structure(c(18747, 18747, 18747,
> 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747,
> 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747), class = "Date")), class = c("grouped_df",
> "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
> Coach340BClaimsID = c(206L, 629L, 4174L, 5302L, 5314L, 5904L,
> 7439L, 7948L, 8268L, 8302L, 10556L, 10893L, 11681L, 12133L,
> 12479L, 12738L, 13145L, 13614L, 14474L, 15187L), .rows = structure(list(
> 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L,
> 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",
> "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
> ), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .drop = TRUE))

Comment: Can you provide `dput(d1)` and `dput(d2)`?

Comment: Change `max` to `pmax` - assuming you want the row-wise max of Invoicing and Invoiced? Which could skip the `ifelse` and use `mutate(Invoicing = pmax(Invoicing, Invoiced))` assuming everything's a `Date` class already.

Comment: If you need more help: If the first `mutate`s run fine, don't include them in the question, they're just clutter. Share `dput(df1[1:10, c("Invoicing", "Invoiced")])` for a reproducible sample of the two columns relevant to the problem line. Pick rows other than `1:10` if needed to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Hi, I added the dputs above. Please let me know if you need more.

Comment: @GregorThomas here is the requested dput: dput(merged_final.1[1:10, c("Invoicing", "Invoiced")])
structure(list(Invoicing = structure(c(NA, NA, 18842, NA, NA, 
18922, NA, 18842, 18842, NA), class = "Date"), Invoiced = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 18842, NA, NA, 18932, NA, 18838, 18842, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @GregorThomas, I cannot use `mutate(Invoicing = pmax(Invoicing, Invoiced))` because I only want this statement to occur if invoicing is greater than invoiced to begin with.

I switched max to pmax and it still did not work

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I used your `dput` data and your code runs without error on it. You may try switching `ifelse()` to `if_else()`. The `dplyr::if_else` is stricter on data types.

Comment: If you need more help, **please shorten your example!** Run the first few lines that work and assign the result: `test <- left_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  mutate(New = coalesce(New, New2)) %>% 
  mutate(New =  pmin(New, Approved, Processed, Rejected, Expired, Pending, Has_Note, Invoice.Pending, Invoicing, Invoiced, Invoice.Rejected, Invoice.Rejected.Needs.Credit, Credited, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-New2)`, then share only the relevant columns of `test` in the question: `dput(test[1:10, c("Invoicing", "Invoiced")])`. But first make sure that the sample demonstrates the problem!

Comment: @GregorThomas Please put that answer in the answers so it can be approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain *why* it happens in the first place, but the attempted fix of adding `%>% as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01")` won't work because this command will attempt to change the **entire** data frame to Date type.

What does work is changing only the affected column to Date:

```
left_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  [...]
  mutate(Invoicing = if_else(Invoicing > Invoiced,
                             max(Invoicing, Invoiced),
                             Invoicing),
         Invoicing = as.Date(Invoicing, origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

And using if_else() instead of ifelse() works too, as suggested by Gregor Thomas in the comments.

Comment: `if_else` was just a guess, not an answer. As I said in comments, using OP's data I did not have a problem. There might be a version issue as well...

Comment: They have now. And also the Q has been closed, so I can't add it as an answer.